# Bidirectional A* not finding the shortest path

Tags: python, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, bidirectional

I'm implementing bidirectional `A*` algorithm in Python 2.7.12 and testing it on the map of Romania from from Russell and Norvig, Chapter 3. The edges have weights and the aim is to find the shortest path between two nodes.

Here is the visualization of the testing graph:

[image]

The example where my Bidirectional A* is failing is that where the starting point is `'a'` and the goal is `'u'`. This is the path that my implementation has found:
[image: My path]
The length of `['a', 's', 'f', 'b', 'u']` is `535`.

This is the actual shortest path from `'a'` to `'u'`:
[image: The shortest path]
The length of `['a', 's', 'r', 'p', 'b', 'u']` is `503`.

As we can see, my implementation failed to find the shortest path. I think that the problem may be in my stopping conditions, but I don't know.

This is the python script with my implementation of A* (I used Euclidean distance as a heuristic) and few other help classes and functions:

```
from __future__ import division
import math
from networkx import *
import random
import pickle
import sys
import heapq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class PriorityQueue():
    """Implementation of a priority queue"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = []
        self.node_finder = dict()
        self.current = 0
        self.REMOVED_SYMBOL = '<removed>'

    def next(self):
        if self.current >=len(self.queue):
            self.current
            raise StopIteration

        out = self.queue[self.current]
        self.current += 1
        return out

    def pop(self):
        while self.queue:
            node = heapq.heappop(self.queue)
            nodeId = node[1]
            if nodeId is not self.REMOVED_SYMBOL:
                try:
                    del self.node_finder[nodeId]
                except KeyError:
                    dummy=1
                return node

    def remove(self, nodeId):
        node = self.node_finder[nodeId]
        node[1] = self.REMOVED_SYMBOL

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return 'PQ:[%s]'%(', '.join([str(i) for i in self.queue]))

    def append(self, node):
        nodeId = node[1]
        nodePriority = node[0]
        node = [nodePriority, nodeId]
        self.node_finder[nodeId] = node
        heapq.heappush(self.queue, node)

    def update(self, node):
        nodeId = node[1]
        nodePriority = node[0]
        node = [nodePriority, nodeId]
        self.remove(nodeId)
        self.node_finder[nodeId] = node
        heapq.heappush(self.queue, node)

    def getPriority(self, nodeId):
        return self.node_finder[nodeId][0]

    def __contains__(self, key):
        self.current = 0
        return key in [n for v,n in self.queue]

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self == other

    def size(self):
        return len(self.queue)

    def clear(self):
        self.queue = []

    def top(self):
        return self.queue[0]

    __next__ = next

def bidirectional_a_star(graph, start, goal):
    if start == goal:
        return []

    pq_s = PriorityQueue()
    pq_t = PriorityQueue()
    closed_s = dict()
    closed_t = dict()
    g_s = dict()
    g_t = dict()

    g_s[start] = 0
    g_t[goal] = 0

    cameFrom1 = dict()
    cameFrom2 = dict()

    def euclidean_distance(graph, v, goal):
        xv, yv = graph.node[v]['pos']
        xg, yg = graph.node[goal]['pos']
        return ((xv-xg)**2 + (yv-yg)**2)**0.5

    def h1(v): # heuristic for forward search (from start to goal)
        return euclidean_distance(graph, v, goal)

    def h2(v): # heuristic for backward search (from goal to start)
        return euclidean_distance(graph, v, start)

    cameFrom1[start] = False
    cameFrom2[goal] = False

    pq_s.append((0+h1(start), start)) 
    pq_t.append((0+h2(goal), goal))

    done = False
    i = 0

    mu = 10**301 # 10**301 plays the role of infinity
    connection = None

    while pq_s.size() > 0 and pq_t.size() > 0 and done == False:
        i = i + 1
        if i % 2 == 1: # alternate between forward and backward A*
            fu, u = pq_s.pop()
            closed_s[u] = True
            for v in graph[u]:
                weight = graph[u][v]['weight']
                if v in g_s:
                    if g_s[u] + weight < g_s[v]:
                        g_s[v] = g_s[u] + weight
                        cameFrom1[v] = u
                        if v in closed_s:
                            del closed_s[v]
                        if v in pq_s:
                            pq_s.update((g_s[v]+h1(v), v))
                        else:
                            pq_s.append((g_s[v]+h1(v), v))
                else:
                    g_s[v] = g_s[u] + weight
                    cameFrom1[v] = u
                    pq_s.append((g_s[v]+h1(v), v))
                if v in closed_t:
                    if g_s[u] + weight + g_t[v] < mu:
                        mu = g_s[u] + weight + g_t[v]
                        connection = v
                        done = True
        else:
            fu, u = pq_t.pop()
            closed_t[u] = True
            for v in graph[u]:
                weight = graph[u][v]['weight']
                if v in g_t:
                    if g_t[u] + weight < g_t[v]:
                        g_t[v] = g_t[u] + weight
                        cameFrom2[v] = u
                        if v in closed_t:
                            del closed_t[v]
                        if v in pq_t:
                            pq_t.update((g_t[v]+h2(v), v))
                        else:
                            pq_t.append((g_t[v]+h2(v), v))
                else:
                    g_t[v] = g_t[u] + weight
                    cameFrom2[v] = u
                    pq_t.append((g_t[v]+h2(v), v))
                if v in closed_s:
                    if g_t[u] + weight + g_s[v] < mu:
                        mu = g_t[u] + weight + g_s[v] 
                        connection = v
                        done = True

        if u in closed_s and u in closed_t:
            if g_s[u] + g_t[u] < mu:
                mu = g_s[u] + g_t[u]
                connection = u
                stopping_distance = min(min([f for (f,x) in pq_s]), min([f for (f,x) in pq_t]))
                if mu <= stopping_distance:
                    done = True
                    #connection = u
                    continue

    if connection is None:
        # start and goal are not connected
        return None

    #print cameFrom1
    #print cameFrom2

    path = []
    current = connection
    #print current
    while current != False:
        #print predecessor
        path = [current] + path
        current = cameFrom1[current]

    current = connection
    successor = cameFrom2[current]
    while successor != False:
        path = path + [successor]
        current = successor
        successor = cameFrom2[current]

    return path


# This function visualizes paths
def draw_graph(graph, node_positions={}, start=None, goal=None, path=[]):

    explored = list(graph.get_explored_nodes())

    labels ={}
    for node in graph:
        labels[node]=node

    if not node_positions:
        node_positions = networkx.spring_layout(graph)

    edge_labels = networkx.get_edge_attributes(graph,'weight')

    networkx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph, node_positions)
    networkx.draw_networkx_edges(graph, node_positions, style='dashed')
    networkx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(graph, node_positions, edge_labels=edge_labels)
    networkx.draw_networkx_labels(graph,node_positions, labels)

    networkx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph, node_positions, nodelist=explored, node_color='g') 

    if path:
        edges = [(path[i], path[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(path)-1)]
        networkx.draw_networkx_edges(graph, node_positions, edgelist=edges, edge_color='b')

    if start:
        networkx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph, node_positions, nodelist=[start], node_color='b')

    if goal:
        networkx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph, node_positions, nodelist=[goal], node_color='y')


    plt.plot()
    plt.show()

# this function calculates the length of the path
def calculate_length(graph, path):
    pairs = zip(path, path[1:])
    return sum([graph.get_edge_data(a, b)['weight'] for a, b in pairs])

#Romania map data from Russell and Norvig, Chapter 3.
romania = pickle.load(open('romania_graph.pickle', 'rb'))

node_positions = {n: romania.node[n]['pos'] for n in romania.node.keys()}

start = 'a'
goal = 'u'

path = bidirectional_a_star(romania, start, goal)
print "This is the path found by bidirectional A* :", path
print "Its length :", calculate_length(romania, path)
# visualize my path
draw_graph(romania, node_positions=node_positions, start=start, goal=goal, path=path)


# compare to the true shortest path between start and goal

true_path = networkx.shortest_path(romania, start, goal, weight='weight')
print "This is the actual shortest path: ", true_path
print "Its lenght: ", calculate_length(romania, true_path)
#visualize true_path
draw_graph(romania, node_positions=node_positions, start=start, goal=goal, path=true_path)
```

Pickle data for Romania can be downloaded from [here](http://www.filedropper.com/romaniagraph).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected some errors in `PriorityQueue` and `bidirectional_a_star`. It's working fine now.

The corrected code for the class and the function is as follows:

```
class PriorityQueue():
    """Implementation of a priority queue"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = []
        self.node_finder = dict()
        self.current = 0
        self.REMOVED_SYMBOL = '<removed>'

    def next(self):
        if self.current >=len(self.queue):
            self.current
            raise StopIteration

        out = self.queue[self.current]
        while out == self.REMOVED_SYMBOL:
            self.current += 1
            out = self.queue[self.current]
        self.current += 1
        return out

    def pop(self):
        # TODO: finish this
        while self.queue:
            node = heapq.heappop(self.queue)
            nodeId = node[1]
            if nodeId is not self.REMOVED_SYMBOL:
                try:
                    del self.node_finder[nodeId]
                except KeyError:
                    dummy=1
                return node
        #raise KeyError('pop from an empty priority queue')

    def remove(self, nodeId):
        node = self.node_finder[nodeId]
        node[1] = self.REMOVED_SYMBOL

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return 'PQ:[%s]'%(', '.join([str(i) for i in self.queue]))

    def append(self, node):
        # node = (priority, nodeId)
        nodeId = node[1]
        nodePriority = node[0]
        node = [nodePriority, nodeId]
        self.node_finder[nodeId] = node
        heapq.heappush(self.queue, node)

    def update(self, node):
        nodeId = node[1]
        nodePriority = node[0]
        node = [nodePriority, nodeId]
        self.remove(nodeId)
        self.node_finder[nodeId] = node
        heapq.heappush(self.queue, node)

    def getPriority(self, nodeId):
        return self.node_finder[nodeId][0]

    def __contains__(self, key):
        self.current = 0
        return key in [n for v,n in self.queue]

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self == other

    def size(self):
        return len([1 for priority, node in self.queue if node!=self.REMOVED_SYMBOL])

    def clear(self):
        self.queue = []

    def top(self):
        return self.queue[0]

    __next__ = next

def bidirectional_a_star(graph, start, goal):
    if start == goal:
        return []

    pq_s = PriorityQueue()
    pq_t = PriorityQueue()
    closed_s = dict()
    closed_t = dict()
    g_s = dict()
    g_t = dict()

    g_s[start] = 0
    g_t[goal] = 0

    cameFrom1 = dict()
    cameFrom2 = dict()

    def euclidean_distance(graph, v, goal):
        xv, yv = graph.node[v]['pos']
        xg, yg = graph.node[goal]['pos']
        return ((xv-xg)**2 + (yv-yg)**2)**0.5

    def h1(v): # heuristic for forward search (from start to goal)
        return euclidean_distance(graph, v, goal)

    def h2(v): # heuristic for backward search (from goal to start)
        return euclidean_distance(graph, v, start)

    cameFrom1[start] = False
    cameFrom2[goal] = False

    pq_s.append((0+h1(start), start)) 
    pq_t.append((0+h2(goal), goal))

    done = False
    i = 0

    mu = 10**301 # 10**301 plays the role of infinity
    connection = None

    while pq_s.size() > 0 and pq_t.size() > 0 and done == False:
        i = i + 1
        if i % 2 == 1: # alternate between forward and backward A*
            fu, u = pq_s.pop()
            closed_s[u] = True
            for v in graph[u]:
                weight = graph[u][v]['weight']
                if v in g_s:
                    if g_s[u] + weight < g_s[v]:
                        g_s[v] = g_s[u] + weight
                        cameFrom1[v] = u
                        if v in closed_s:
                            del closed_s[v]
                        if v in pq_s:
                            pq_s.update((g_s[v]+h1(v), v))
                        else:
                            pq_s.append((g_s[v]+h1(v), v))
                else:
                    g_s[v] = g_s[u] + weight
                    cameFrom1[v] = u
                    pq_s.append((g_s[v]+h1(v), v))
        else:
            fu, u = pq_t.pop()
            closed_t[u] = True
            for v in graph[u]:
                weight = graph[u][v]['weight']
                if v in g_t:
                    if g_t[u] + weight < g_t[v]:
                        g_t[v] = g_t[u] + weight
                        cameFrom2[v] = u
                        if v in closed_t:
                            del closed_t[v]
                        if v in pq_t:
                            pq_t.update((g_t[v]+h2(v), v))
                        else:
                            pq_t.append((g_t[v]+h2(v), v))
                else:
                    g_t[v] = g_t[u] + weight
                    cameFrom2[v] = u
                    pq_t.append((g_t[v]+h2(v), v))

        if u in closed_s and u in closed_t:
            if g_s[u] + g_t[u] < mu:
                mu = g_s[u] + g_t[u]
                connection = u
                try:
                    stopping_distance = max(min([f for (f,x) in pq_s]), min([f for (f,x) in pq_t]))
                except ValueError:
                    continue
                if mu <= stopping_distance:
                    done = True
                    connection = u
                    continue

    if connection is None:
        # start and goal are not connected
        return None

    #print cameFrom1
    #print cameFrom2

    path = []
    current = connection
    #print current
    while current != False:
        #print predecessor
        path = [current] + path
        current = cameFrom1[current]

    current = connection
    successor = cameFrom2[current]
    while successor != False:
        path = path + [successor]
        current = successor
        successor = cameFrom2[current]

    return path
```